# Comprehensive list of all possible AppType values in DPROJ file?

Tags: delphi, project, delphi-11-alexandria

The Delphi DPROJ file contains an `AppType` XML tag-pair, for example:

```
<AppType>Application</AppType>
```

...where the value of `AppType` could be: 'Application', 'Library', 'Package', etc. etc.

Where is a comprehensive list of all possible `AppType` values?

Also, in some cases, the `AppType` XML tag-pair is missing or is empty in the DPROJ file. What are the conditions to make the `AppType` XML tag missing from the DPROJ file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some constants declared in *ToolsAPI.pas*:

```
  { Default IDE application/project types }
  sApplication = 'Application';
  sLibrary = 'Library';
  sConsole = 'Console';
  sPackage = 'Package';
  sStaticLibrary = 'StaticLibrary';
  sOptionSet = 'OptionSet';
//  sAndroidService = 'AndroidService';
```

This list may be extended in the future.

Comment: The `ToolsAPI.pas`file for Delphi 11 Alexandria is located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\ToolsAPI\ToolsAPI.pas 
It's `uses` clause contains 3 units that cannot be found (at least without modification): `DockForm`, `DesignIntf`, `PersonalityConst`. Should I modify the `ToolsAPI.pas` file?

Comment: Why should you want to modify ToolsApi.pas? Anyway, it is only there for documentation and never compiled nor are you supposed to compile it. Changes would not have any impact. If you write an IDE plugin, you must add DesignIDE to the requires clause, but if you want a standalone program and need the constants simply copy them.

Comment: "Why should you want to modify ToolsApi.pas?" If I **WOULD** compile it then I would have to fix the erroneous `uses` elements. - However, thanks for pointing me to `ToolsAPI.pas`.

Comment: Compiling `ToolsAPI.pas` unit wont help you in any way. Why? Because this units is part of the Delphi IDE source code and has already been compiled into Delphi IDE. So why is  it then shipped with Delphi. It is shipped with Delphi in order to help people write Delphi extensions that use this API without the need to write extensive documentation of the API. And the reason why there are some Units in uses clause and not present in Delphi installation is because those units are pert of the rest of Delphi IDE soucecode that hasn't been published by Embarcadero.

Comment: Another reason of why you don't want to mess around with `ToolsAPI.pas` is next internal comment that you can find on the beginning of the mentione unit `Before making modifications to this unit, please see senior IDE R&D engineer !!!`. So if Embarcadero Employees needs to consult with `IDE R&D engineer` before making any change what makes you think that regular Delphi users would benefit from modifying this unit by themselves?